# How can add condition on tree view and change color according to conditions using odoo?

Tags: odoo

How can add condition on tree view and change color according to conditions using odoo 10

Comment: I would advice you to add some code you tried. It will increase the chances of getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: And please add the Odoo version to your question.

Answer (score 0):

With `colors` attribute on the tree node. Example:

```
<tree colors="red:notes!=False">
```

Generic:

```
<tree colors="<color_name>:<condition>">
```